# how serialize a system.Drawing.Image into stream in c#?

Tags: c#, image, serialization

I have an Image object, img, and i need to save it into a memory stream.

Save method has this signature:

Image.Save (Stream, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters)

but i don't know what i shoud provide in parameters 2 and 3.

I workaround problem using BinaryFormmater serialization, but i would like use the most appropriate method.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Use the [other prototype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and just specify [ImageFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simpler overload: [`Image.Save(Stream, ImageFormat)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx). The second parameter lets you pick the format you want to save the image on, like BMP, PNG, or JPEG.

```
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp); // if you need to access the pixels, perhaps
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png); // lossless compression (good for drawings)
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // lossy but powerful compression (good for photos)
```

Comment: yes, i saw this overload, but i don't know which parameter to provide.. :(

Comment: @stefano: it depends on what you want to do with the serialized image. Without knowing that, there isn't much more we can tell you.

Comment: thx a lot! it was i needed!
i thought (wrongly) i could not save in Bmp format a .jpg file, for this, it was not clear to me mean of the parameters.. now all is clear!

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142148.aspx) has the information you need. On that page, they list this as the easiest way to get the ImageCodecInfo:

```
public static ImageCodecInfo FindEncoder(ImageFormat format) { 
    if (format == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("format");

    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()) {
        if (codec.FormatID.Equals(format.Guid)) {
            return codec;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```